# Undo History as panel

Tags: interface

I like Edit -> Undo History in Blender 3.
But what I find annoying is that it is hidden in a menu. Sometimes it would be practical to see directly at a glance where you are in the history.
Is there a possibility for this? Possibly as an addon?

[image: History Menu]

[image: History Panel]

Comment: This is a Q&A site for problems with using Blender. If you have a suggestion for a new feature you should post it at https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/.

Comment: It is also a question of whether this possibility exists.
But from your statement I assume that it is not yet possible. @JohnEason

Comment: There is nothing native that does that, but it may be possible through python scripting, if you roll your sleeves up

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks. I will look into it.
Do you happen to know how I can access it?
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.ed.html?highlight=history#bpy.ops.ed.undo_history
Doesn't include a method that allows you to read the history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go into the *Preferences > Keymap > Screen > Screen (Global)*, then at the bottom click on the *Add New* button and in the new function type *ed.undo_history* and choose the shortcut:

[image]

Now when you press your shortcut it opens a pop-up:

[image]

Or as suggested by John Eason, right click on the *Edit > Undo History* fuction in order to add it to the *Quick Favorites* panel

Comment: Oooo. That's one I didn't know about. Useful! You could also add it to the Quick Favorites by the look of it. (Right-click the menu entry and choose "Add to Quick Favorites").

Comment: oh yes you're right, quick favorite as well

Comment: Well, that is of course also sufficient. I'll put it directly on a button on my tablet. It's also handy to know that there are several such options in Blender that you can place on a button.